# Custom Daemon with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I'm trying to create a custom daemon that loads up the Rails environment.
My environment is as follows: 
ruby-1.9.2-p180
rails 3.0.5

I did the following:

-Installed the daemons gem

-Installed daemon_generator plugin found here:
https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator

-Generated a daemon: rails generate daemon listener

All this worked fine.  When I run the daemon, it works.

However, as soon as I try to access an active record object like trying to retrieve a user, it blows up.

```
*** below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally ***
#<NameError: method `recognize' not defined in Rack::Mount::RouteSet>
*** below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***
#<NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory>
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
#<fatal: exception reentered>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass>
#<NameError: method `recognize' not defined in Rack::Mount::RouteSet>
```

Any thoughts on how to create a Daemon that loads up Rails 3.0.5?

Comment: I'm having the same error here. I can't even the run the daemon as is. I'm using ree-1.8.7-2011.03. Sorry to be of no help.

Comment: I'm getting this same error using rvm ruby-1.9.2-p136 and rails 3.0.7.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I prefer to roll my own rails daemon controllers. Here is a simple example that works for most cases:

script/daemon

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

ENV["APP_ROOT"] ||= File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/..")
ENV["RAILS_ENV_PATH"] ||= "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/config/environment.rb"

script = "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/daemons/#{ARGV[1]}"

Daemons.run(script, dir_mode: :normal, dir: "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/tmp/pids")
```

daemons/your_daemon_script.rb

```
require ENV["RAILS_ENV_PATH"]
loop { 
  ... your code ...
}
```

You can control your deamons by using the following commands:

```
script/daemon run your_daemon_script.rb
script/daemon start your_daemon_script.rb
script/daemon stop your_daemon_script.rb
```

This enables me to easily add new daemons and I can easily load rails in each script if necessary.

Comment: Why is rubygems a requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of problems trying get daemon_generator working.  I got my daemon working by skipping the daemon_generator all together and just using the daemons gem (v1.1.3).

in urserver_control.rb (in root ruby app directory):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'daemons'
    require 'TweetMsg'

    Daemons.run('urserver.rb')
```

in urserver.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'environmen
t'))
require "rubygems"

  --- insert your code here ---
```

You can test by running your server directly `ruby urserver.rb` or `ruby urserver_controller run`
And then once that is working starting and stopping the controller`ruby urserver_control.rb {start | stop | run }`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code in https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator/blob/master/lib/generators/daemon/templates/script.rb it appears they load things in the wrong order...

Looking at my delayed_job daemon script and config.ru they load config/environment.rb (which in turn loads application.rb and initializes the app)

So a possible fix would be to edit the generated script and make it only require 'config/environment.rb'

I tried this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 # You might want to change this
 ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "development"

 require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"

 $running = true
 Signal.trap("TERM") do
   $running = false
 end

 while($running) do

   # Replace this with your code
   Rails.logger.auto_flushing = true
   o = Order.last
   Rails.logger.info "The latest order is #{o.id}"

   sleep 10
 end
```

and it yielded no errors... (Tried both Rails 3.0.3 and 3.0.5)

Comment: Interesting, which version of Ruby were you running?  I tried this exactly and got the original poster's error using rvm ruby-1.9.2-p136 and rails 3.0.7

Answer (score 0):

I had problems running daemon as is on my staging server (Rails 3.0.7, ruby 1.8.7, passenger 3.0.0). Neither

require File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/../../config/application"
Rails.application.require_environment!

nor

require File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/../config/environment"

Worked.

I fixed it by re-installing the standard config.ru in rails root (which I had de-installed to integrate w passenger... not sure now how I will get daemons & passenger to work together now ...)