# How run twitterstream in background and store statuses into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, twitter-streaming-api

I am using [twitterstream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream) to fetch tweets from twitter and store them to the database. I have been successful in fetching the tweets but not able to run it in the background. Can any one tell me how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: How to run things in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897605/ruby-on-rails-how-to-run-things-in-the-background)

Comment: Are you doing this within a Rails project? twitterstream isn't Rails specific.

Comment: @muffinista: Yes.. in a rails project

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would look at [Custom Daemon with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441221/custom-daemon-with-rails-3) and see if it helps. You have two main options -- load your tweets every couple of minutes via cron, or run a background daemon.  The daemon will probably make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of work can be handled in a background worker. [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) is a current and great background worker library, and there's a [RailsCast on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).