# Execute ruby method's by time

Tags: ruby, task

I never do task's in ruby (without Rails). Now i need do to such thing:

Let's say i have 3 methods in ruby class:

```
a, b, c
```

in main method i need to execute method's via time, so that method run's not when i run script, but when time has come, for example:

a first must be executed in 11:59:30
then in xx-xx-xx, than in loop

a first must be executed in 12:00:30
then in xx-xx-xx, than in loop

etc

What i need to write, to google, or maybe give me simple example how can i do this?

**can i do something like sleep until time == 14-50... ?**

Comment: It's called scheduling: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling

Comment: @Stefan and what? i need some examples, here https://github.com/javan/whenever i see examples with Rails

Comment: You might want to look at using some kind of background job process. A Rails Ruby process can run perpetually if you set it up that way. [Some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441221/custom-daemon-with-rails-3).

Comment: So you are wanting to have a *single* Ruby task with several methods, where each method is run on a different schedule? Or are you wanting all *different* Ruby tasks run at different times? If the latter, I'd probably use a cron job on Linux, or Windows scheduler on Windows. If you want a single Ruby task be able to schedule internal methods, some of the referenced schedulers don't seem to do that.

Answer (score 1):

use `sleep t` to sleep `t` seconds.

for example `a` will run each `t_a` second. `b` in `t_b` and `c` in `t_c` seconds.

```
time = 0;
while true do
 a if time % t_a == 0
 b if time % t_b == 0
 c if time % t_c == 0
 time += 1
 sleep 1
end
```

Comment: can i do something like sleep until time == 14-50... ?